# Symfony2 "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" doens't add a column to table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to add a column to a table through doctrine command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I know it can do that, since I've done that before and documentation states that clearly:

"In other words, if you add a new property with mapping metadata to Product and run this task again, it will generate the "alter table" statement needed to add that new column to the existing product table."

The following is the field I'm trying to add as a column:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="service_machine_name", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
 */
private $serviceMachineName;
```

But when I type:
    php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

It tells me that my database is in sync with my current entity, but it clearly is not, because I have an additional field in my entity class.

I also tried shortening the column name to 3 letters (just in case), but it still doesn't add a column!

Note: I have added columns to a different table on the same database (which is remote) and it worked fine before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first create setter and getter for that columns like this

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/User
```

after that you have to use

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Thank you! I generated getters/setters and when I ran the --force command, it still showed the same table (with no new column). Then regeneratted the entity and added some test fields, but when i ran --force again, doctrine tried to create table based on old components and showed error: "Property......does not exist"....Do you by any chance have any ideas why it doesn't create table based on new fields??

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22198323/2400373

But don't work in symfony 3, for this version is necessary a change, the code is:

You have to first create setter and getter for that columns like this

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/User
```

after that you have to use

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```